# Piping Blender Camera to Python OpenCV webcam

Tags: python, camera

I have a Python OpenCV computer vision script that runs object detection on videos and webcams.
Currently, I'm simulating a scene in Blender, rendering to an mp4 and then opening it separately in Python. This creates a really long cycle time because the Blender render takes about 10-20 minutes for each small change.

Ideally, I would want the camera in Blender to output to a virtual webcam on my computer that OpenCV could then read from, live. I think it would be possible since they are both Python. Is this possible? I also recognize that having a live rendered feed would probably require eevee over cycles.

Comment: As far as I know, no.  It's possible to add hooks to frame change events and use those hooks to output a screen capture to a network socket, but the screen captures take longer than a frame time at 24fps.  I don't know if hooks exist based on moving the scene point of view, but I believe not.

Answer (score -1):

I found only one existing way:

1. First you need allow Terminal to access to your Camera (*1)
2. Run Blender from Terminal `shell /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender`

Check your permisses in System Properties > Privacy and policy > Camera
[image]

*1 : create simply code [sample code](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html) name it as `sample.py` and run it in your terminal `python ./sample.py` -> allow Camera access.

and thats it!

Comment: I think this might be a misunderstanding, I think this would allow Blender to use the webcam? What I want is the camera from Blender to output to a webcam that Python could read using opencv's cv2.VideoCapture()

Comment: Yes Sorry, I  posted this response to other problem! My apologies